# How to produce Front End from existing Restfull Web Service

Tags: java, rest, jsp, frontend, backend

i have this situation and i dont know how to manage.
I am a back end developer but now i should develop the front end part.
( i have use years ago jsp+servlet where the servlet called some util class that extract data from the db directly ). 
I have create the Back End part and i am exposing Restful WebService and this service produce a Json.

Now the problem is coming when i need to develop the front end. 
Whitch technology should i use to call the Restfull webservice, to take the JSON file, to extract the content and to send it to front end.
I have use only JSP and Servlet before but totaly in another way.
I cannot use Angular cause i dont have time to learn it and to write the code.
Some one knows some library to work with JSON and send the data to front end?

Best Regards

Comment: AJAX is probably worth looking into

Answer (score -1):

If you don't have time to learn Angular, you could consider [Create React App](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app) - at least for just this piece of your front end work.

CRA is a boilerplate for a React app maintained by Facebook. It has a very simple setup and a gentle learning curving to get your stated with React.

And you could use a Nodejs package like [Axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) to handle your RESTful API requests.

Good luck!